# Braintree Android SDK Drop-in UI not displayed

Tags: android, braintree

I am trying to display the Drop-in UI in my app upon clicking a specific button. I have used the guide from Braintree site but for some reason nothing is happening.

Code below:

**OnClick function:**

```
    public void onClick(View v){
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.showUI_button:
    onBraintreeSubmit(v);
                   break;
}
}
```

**Drop-in functions:**

```
public void onBraintreeSubmit(View v) {
        PaymentRequest paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest()
                .clientToken(token)
                .amount("$10.00")
                .primaryDescription("Awesome payment")
                .secondaryDescription("Using the Client SDK")
                .submitButtonText("Pay");
        startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == BraintreePaymentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce = data.getParcelableExtra(
                        BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE
                );
                String nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
                // Send the nonce to your server.
            }
        }
    }
```

I have checked that the token is returned from the server.
I have also tried by setting the onClick via the xml code of the button and removing the onClick from the java file but the result is the same, no UI shown.

The log has only two lines

```
performCreate Call Injection Manager
Timeline: Activity_idle id:android.os.BinderProxy@etc
```

Any ideas? If more info is needed to understand better let me know

Comment: Have you found the solution to display the paypal UI

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found this there is a "BraintreeFragment" set up part. Braintree documentation needs to be more clear on this I think.
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
      mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(this, mAuthorization);
      // mBraintreeFragment is ready to use!
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
      // There was an issue with your authorization string.
    }
}
```

The above code should work along with the previous code posted. mAuthorization is the token and needs to be valid to show the payment screen (so the variable "token" in the previous code posted which in my code I just have as private but visible from the whole activity). 
Try with the test token that they have on their page and if this works then the main setup is ok. 
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v2

For setting up tokens on your server, they have further documentation so that those test tokens work on the sandbox.